# Semantic UI Dropdown not selecting properly when a value and an option text are the same

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

When creating [dropdowns with Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html) in a select tag. If the value of an option is the same as the text of a different option, the last option child will be the one selected. Regardless of the option that is selected.

HTML:

```
<select class="ui search dropdown">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="a" selected>This is option A</option>
  <option value="b">This is option B</option>
  <option value="c">a</option>
  <option value="d">This is option D</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$('.dropdown').dropdown();
```

The selected value should be a => "This is option A", but instead value c => "a" is selected.

I have tried different settings and options for the dropdown with no success. Am I missing something or is this a problem with Semantic UI?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/941qxyx0/)

Comment: Identified as a bug from its repo issues, https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/5817